How to properly construct nests for nested logit using mlogit
I am having difficulty constructing the nest correctly according to the logic that mlogit wants. My outcome variable has 4 choices A,B,C,D. However, you first choose between A or not A. Then, you choose between B and not B. Finally, you choose between C or D (or C and not C).
I was first trying a simpler nest where it is just A, B, C, where you first choose between A and not A, and then choose between B and C. This is the nest I have for this:
nests <- list(
  OP1 = c("A"),
  OP2 = c("B","C")
)

But I get an error that seems to indicate I cannot have only one option in a nest. I also tried:
nests <- list(
  OP1 = c("A","OP2"),
  OP2 = c("B","C")
)

But this doesn't work either since "OP2" is not among my actual choices.
I would like to kindly ask for an answer for this simpler question and for my more complex question of adding a nested nest.
